# R: Applying function to single value in data.table 1 and comparing resulting individual values in vector with single values in data.table 2

Tags: vector, merge, data.table, lookup, fault-tolerance

I know how to apply a function to a column in data.table, receive a single value and compare within the same data.table. But, since I am a novice, I do not know how to compare the the result from the function with another data.table. What is special in this case is that the result from the function is a vector. I am not good with words so here is an example instead.

Example data. I have values in a data.table, dt1:

```
## dt1
id <- c("p1","p2","p3","p3","p3",
        "p4","p4","p4","p4","p4",
        "p4","MJF2_157","MJF2_157","MJF3_30","MJF3_30",
        "MJF3_30","MJF3_30","MJF3_30","MJF3_30") 

mass_Da <- c(45659.18,45589.87,45589.19,45610.22,45802.85,
             45660.37,45634.28,45611.12,45589.83,45569.70,
             20838.62,20952.07,20951.89,23539.60,46860.72,
             46839.05,47851.63,46909.48,47555.12)

dt1 <- data.table(id,mass_Da)
```

This is the function I'd like to apply on each row in column "mass" results in a vector for each mass:

```
ld <- function(m,n=5:60){
  ldx <- (m+1.0078*n)/n
  return(ldx[ldx>1000 & ldx<2000])
}
```

The resulting vector should be compare to values by id in another data.table, dt2. If the value in the column masstal also is found in the vector, the corresponding mass from the vector should be displayed in dt2. If no match is found a "no" should be the out put. If several, each vector should be compared to each masstal within the same id. Notice that the length is of the columns in dt1 is never the same as in dt2:

```
### dt2 
id <- c("p1","p2","p3","p3","p3",
        "p4","p4","p4","MJF2_157","MJF2_157",
        "MJF3_157","MJF3_30","MJF3_30","MJF3_30","MJF3_30",
        "MJF3_61","MJF3_61","MJF3_61","MJF3_61","MJF3_61")
length(id)

masstal <- c(1689.770,1341.931,1086.698,1304.001,1433.335,
             1425.521,1989.758,1173.885,1384.406,1065.691,
             1073.079,1742.961,1384.798,1090.666,1447.482,
             1057.163,1173.785,1304.204,1557.331,1149.469)
length(masstal)

dt2 <- data.table(id,masstal)
```

Lastly the match should be done with a tolerance of +-0.5. If it works out the ideal dt should look like this:

```
dt2$confirmed_mass <- c("no",45489.87,45489.19,45489.19,"no",
                        "X","no","no","no","no",
                        "no","no","no",46860.72,"no",
                        "NA","NA","NA","NA","NA")
```

But there is still a problem if the tolerance accepts masstal from two or more mass, here labelled with "X" .

I have tried merging the dt:s but it seems like a detour... and I am still stuck and can not figure out how to compare with a vector.

```
dt_merge <- merge.data.table(dt1,dt2, by=.EACHI, allow.cartesian=TRUE)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your `ld` function is confusing me: if it is to be run on each row of `dt1`, and its logic suggests that it can return length-0 or length much greater than 56 for each row, that means that over 19 rows it can create between 0 and 1064 values. Is this correct? (Even if it is "unlikely" to produce that many for whatever reason, it still seems possible.)

Comment: FYI, it is really bad practice to try to store both numeric values (`45489.87`) and strings (`"no"` or `"X"` or the string literal `"NA"`) in the same vector. Your numbers are converted to strings, and while _yes_ you can convert them back at some time, it is not without inefficiency and possibly risk. I recommend having two columns, one that is strictly `numeric` and could contain `NA` if no number can be applied, and another column that contains `NA` (or some other "goodness" indicator) if the number is good or `"X"` or `"no"` based on whatever problems might have arisen.

Comment: @r2evans,  Yes it is bad practice, and yes it is better with two columns, thanks.

I can understand if the id column is a bit confusing. The reason is that each id can produce different number of data in the two assays (dt1 and 2).

Answer (score 0):

Up front, I'll assume some of your numbers are typos in the `confirmed_mass` column, some do not exist in any data you provided.

Try this:

```r
dt1long <- dt1[, list(lapply(mass_Da, ld)), by = dt1
               ][, c(lapply(.SD, function(z) rep(z, times = lengths(V1))),
                     list(V1 = unlist(V1))),
                 .SDcols = c("id", "mass_Da")]
dt1long
#           id  mass_Da       V1
#       <char>    <num>    <num>
#   1:      p1 45659.18 1986.190
#   2:      p1 45659.18 1903.474
#   3:      p1 45659.18 1827.375
#   4:      p1 45659.18 1757.130
#   5:      p1 45659.18 1692.089
#   6:      p1 45659.18 1631.693
#   7:      p1 45659.18 1575.462
#   8:      p1 45659.18 1522.980
#   9:      p1 45659.18 1473.885
#  10:      p1 45659.18 1427.857
#  ---                          
# 380: MJF3_30 47555.12 1252.458
# 381: MJF3_30 47555.12 1220.370
# 382: MJF3_30 47555.12 1189.886
# 383: MJF3_30 47555.12 1160.889
# 384: MJF3_30 47555.12 1133.273
# 385: MJF3_30 47555.12 1106.941
# 386: MJF3_30 47555.12 1081.806
# 387: MJF3_30 47555.12 1057.788
# 388: MJF3_30 47555.12 1034.815
# 389: MJF3_30 47555.12 1012.819
```

That is each row of `dt1` exploded into as many new values as your `ld` function produces. We then join that onto `dt2` and find matches with tolerance. Since I'm inferring that `dt2` does not have guaranteed-unique keys (using floating-point is not safe for that), I'll add one with `rn`, used to re-aggregate back to the original data.

```r
tol <- 0.5
dt2[, c("rn", "masstal1", "masstal2") := .(.I, masstal - tol, masstal + tol)]

dt1long[dt2, on = .(id, V1 >= masstal1, V1 <= masstal2)
        ][, .(mass = na.omit(mass_Da)[1]), by = .(rn, id, masstal, confirmed_mass)
          ][, massfound := fifelse(id %in% dt1$id, !is.na(mass), NA)]
#        rn       id  masstal confirmed_mass     mass massfound
#     <int>   <char>    <num>         <char>    <num>    <lgcl>
#  1:     1       p1 1689.770             no       NA     FALSE
#  2:     2       p2 1341.931       45489.87 45589.87      TRUE
#  3:     3       p3 1086.698       45489.19 45589.19      TRUE
#  4:     4       p3 1304.001       45489.19 45589.19      TRUE
#  5:     5       p3 1433.335             no       NA     FALSE
#  6:     6       p4 1425.521              X 45589.83      TRUE
#  7:     7       p4 1989.758             no       NA     FALSE
#  8:     8       p4 1173.885             no       NA     FALSE
#  9:     9 MJF2_157 1384.406             no       NA     FALSE
# 10:    10 MJF2_157 1065.691             no       NA     FALSE
# 11:    11 MJF3_157 1073.079             no       NA        NA
# 12:    12  MJF3_30 1742.961             no       NA     FALSE
# 13:    13  MJF3_30 1384.798             no       NA     FALSE
# 14:    14  MJF3_30 1090.666       46860.72 46860.72      TRUE
# 15:    15  MJF3_30 1447.482             no       NA     FALSE
# 16:    16  MJF3_61 1057.163             NA       NA        NA
# 17:    17  MJF3_61 1173.785             NA       NA        NA
# 18:    18  MJF3_61 1304.204             NA       NA        NA
# 19:    19  MJF3_61 1557.331             NA       NA        NA
# 20:    20  MJF3_61 1149.469             NA       NA        NA
#        rn       id  masstal confirmed_mass     mass massfound
```

Notes:

- I kept your `confirmed_mass` column (and used it as a "key" for aggregation) solely to do a side-by-side comparison with your data; I assume it is not really part of the original `dt2`, so it should be removed from the `by=` vector.
- I also kept `rn` just to show what it's doing ... it can safely be removed after the join with `dt1long`.
- Per the comments, I broke the results into two columns so that we don't combine numbers and non-numbers. Feel free to re-combine them if you really need them to be. I chose a logical for the second column, since it seemed your intent was ternary: found, not found, or id-not-present.

I don't know the likelihood of this with your real data, but ... if your `ld(.)` function can produce numbers such that two or more are within the `0.5` tolerance, then it is possible that the join would find multiples. In its current state, the code above will silently mask that, with no indication that it occurred nor which of the `mass_Da` matches were returned. If you think this is possible, then we can change `na.omit(.)[1]` (which will always return length-1 *something*) with a list.

```r
dt1long[dt2, on = .(id, V1 >= masstal1, V1 <= masstal2)
        ][, .(mass = list(na.omit(mass_Da))), by = .(rn, id, masstal, confirmed_mass)
          ][, massfound := fifelse(id %in% dt1$id, lengths(mass) > 0, NA)]
#        rn       id  masstal confirmed_mass              mass massfound
#     <int>   <char>    <num>         <char>            <list>    <lgcl>
#  1:     1       p1 1689.770             no                       FALSE
#  2:     2       p2 1341.931       45489.87          45589.87      TRUE
#  3:     3       p3 1086.698       45489.19 45589.19,45610.22      TRUE
#  4:     4       p3 1304.001       45489.19 45589.19,45610.22      TRUE
#  5:     5       p3 1433.335             no                       FALSE
#  6:     6       p4 1425.521              X 45589.83,45569.70      TRUE
#  7:     7       p4 1989.758             no                       FALSE
#  8:     8       p4 1173.885             no                       FALSE
#  9:     9 MJF2_157 1384.406             no                       FALSE
# 10:    10 MJF2_157 1065.691             no                       FALSE
# 11:    11 MJF3_157 1073.079             no                          NA
# 12:    12  MJF3_30 1742.961             no                       FALSE
# 13:    13  MJF3_30 1384.798             no                       FALSE
# 14:    14  MJF3_30 1090.666       46860.72 46860.72,46839.05      TRUE
# 15:    15  MJF3_30 1447.482             no                       FALSE
# 16:    16  MJF3_61 1057.163             NA                          NA
# 17:    17  MJF3_61 1173.785             NA                          NA
# 18:    18  MJF3_61 1304.204             NA                          NA
# 19:    19  MJF3_61 1557.331             NA                          NA
# 20:    20  MJF3_61 1149.469             NA                          NA
#        rn       id  masstal confirmed_mass              mass massfound
```

Note the change to both `na.omit` and to how `massfound` was calculated. Here, `mass` is a list-column, which means you cannot (currently) just do "math" on it without some minor tweaks. Over to you how you want to resolve when multiple matches are found. (For instance, would it be better to return multiple rows for each `rn`-row?)